# how to use TcpListener to work with long tcp connection

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

1. I want to use long Tcp connection instead of short alive.
2. I need to know when the connection is lose, even when unplug network cable,(a few sec/min is acceptable )

I have try follow code

```
 _tcpListener = new TcpListener(endPoint);
            _tcpListener.Start();
            _ = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
              {
                  while (true)
                  {
                      try
                      {
                          var buffer = new Memory<byte>(new byte[1024 * 10]);// 10KB buffer
                          var result = 0;
                          var client = await _tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

                          using (var stream = client.GetStream())
                          {
                              result = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer);
                              this.HandleMessage(buffer.Slice(0, result));
                          }
                      }
                      catch (SocketException e)
                      {
                          NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info(e);
                          HandleMessage(new Memory<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("rtsp://shutdown$")));
                      }
                      catch (Exception e)
                      {
                          NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info(e);
                      }
                  }
              }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

but it seemed it's not a long tcp connection and thus can not detect connection lose.

I also try do another loop after `GetStream()`, but it can not read any data after the first read (to end).

could anyone help me ?  why it seems so different than WebSocket, I can not make it thow any SocketException even I close the client device.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you need:

1. For long live Tcp Connection you can use instead of `_tcpListener.Start()` use `_tcpListener.Start(Int32)` more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.start?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_TcpListener_Start_System_Int32_)
2. To check if your connection is alive, you can use `_tcpListener.Active` property

> true if TcpListener is actively listening; otherwise, false.

Comment: won't  `_tcpListener.Active` is for the `Host` is started or stopped ?

Comment: `Active` Gets a value that indicates whether TcpListener is actively listening for client connections.

Comment: More here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.active?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: for a TcpServer  is can connect to multiple client, and I need to know which client is disconnected, `Active` is a server state so I can not use it